# Front tire and downtube are extremely close

Tags: wheels, frames

I bought a brand new [Oolter Torm S](https://oolter.com/torm-s/)

[image]

The distance between the front wheel and the frame looks normal. However the bike that I got looks like this:

[image]
[image]

I did buy a bike that is slightly too small (framesize 52, I need 56) but I didn't expect the front wheel rubbing the downtube when applying the brakes.

Comment: Why did you buy a 52 if you know you need a 56?

Comment: @MaplePanda There was no 56 lol. Now there is nothing. These Oolter bikes are very rare. I was looking for a cheap road bike with a motor. There's one for 1800chf on bikester now, the 2nd cheapest is already at 3800. This oolter came in at 1200.

Comment: Fair enough. With all due respect, you might want a professional to check over the bike for other assembly errors.

Comment: If it came assembled like that from a "professional" as per your comment below.  I would 100% be send that pic to the professional and/or his employer.  Someone needs some training.

Comment: @MaplePanda: Can’t find a geometry chart, but a size 52 probably only has 2cm less reach and 3cm less stack than a size 56. Easy to compensate with a longer stem (just use a 110mm instead of the default 90mm) and pulling out the seatpost.

Comment: Related questions: [Why the backwards fork?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/72722/why-the-backwards-fork) (same issue on purpose), [Why is the steering so twitchy? Steel 90's MTB fork](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/67950/why-is-the-steering-so-twitchy-steel-90s-mtb-fork) (opposite issue).

Comment: @Michael Fair enough. I suppose there might be some smaller issues (eg. a relatively short wheelbase), but having the fork installed backwards is not helping in that department either.

Comment: @Hursey OP was the professional I believe ;)

Comment: @MaplePanda nah, the stem came pre-assembled. So I ignorantly assumed it was correct

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Your fork is installed backwards. Loosen the stem, rotate the fork 180°, retighten the stem. You'll probably need to adjust the front brake's cable too.

---

Some details that show the fork is installed backwards:

- the [trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_and_motorcycle_geometry#Trail) of the front wheel is negative - wheel trail should always be positive
- the front disc brake should be on the left side of the bike
- the disc caliper is never on the leading edge of the fork

And finally there's a clue in the decoration - the diagonal stripes go the opposite way from the ones in the example :-).
<sub>Thanks to shoover for the details.</sub>

Comment: oh dear... the instruction manual said to let a "professional" assemble the bike. I scoffed... and nearly flew over the handlebars. Such a humbling experience.

Comment: You can tell because (a) the trail is negative and (b) the diagonal stripes go the opposite way from the ones in the example.

Comment: Also, both disc brakes should be on the same side of the bike. And the disc caliper is never on the leading edge of the fork.

Comment: The trail, as defined in the Wikipedia article that is linked, is not negative, it is even *more positive* than it should be. Maybe you meant the fork offset or the *mechanical trail*.

Comment: No offence, @AzulShiva, but if you've made a mistake like this, I'd stop by your LFBS (local friendly bike shop) to have them check the bike and see if you've made any other mistakes. There could be more subtle ones, such as under or overtightening something.

Comment: I'll bet the turn radius is tighter on that setup...

Comment: @SQB the mistake (stem incorrectly assembled) was made by OOLTER. My mistake was not noticing.

Comment: @AzulShiva in that case, I'd have your LFBS check if there's anything else you didn't notice.